# Unable to view the designer of a screen in VS 2010 IDE

Tags: c#, .net

We are unable to view the designer of a screen in VS 2010 IDE, it always throws exception. The call stack of the exception is given below

> Could not load file
>    or assembly 'xxxxx', Version=2.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dba69d426c69de49' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

We have recently ported the screen project from VS 2008 to VS 2010. We never get the designer issue in VS 2008 IDE.

The assembly 'xxxxx' with version 2.1.8.0, that the screen refers is present in the reference path of the project and the assembly is signed (having strong name).

We are facing the same issue in wpf screens also, the call stack is given below.

> **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.**
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast>(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
>
> at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>
> at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)*
>
> **System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   Could not load file or assembly 'xxxxx', Version=2.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=04c8ff473e9eec03' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**
>
> at PreventiveMaintenance.ToolTipConverter.Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
>
> at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
>
> at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)
>
> at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(AttachAttempt attempt)
>
> atSystem.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
>
> at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(Boolean lastChance)
>
> at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(Object arg)
>
> at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
>
> at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
>
> at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
>
> at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
>
> at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
>
> at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
>
> at MS.Internal.DeferredHwndSource.ProcessQueue(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Are you able to verify that the .dll in question is present in the `\bin` folder? Are you able to rebuild the project? I would sometimes get designer issues if the project was out of date (say, if it was a fresh check-out from source control, on a different machine)

Comment: Yes the .dll is present in the referenced path \bin folder and i can rebuild the project successfully.Project is not out of date